# Calculate average values for rows with different ids in MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

File contains information about products per day, and I need to calculate average values for month for **each** product.

Source data looks like this:

```
   A  B           C       D 
   id date        rating price
1  1  2014/01/01  2       20
2  1  2014/01/02  2       20
3  1  2014/01/03  2       20
4  1  2014/01/04  1       20
5  1  2014/01/05  1       20
6  1  2014/01/06  1       20
7  1  2014/01/07  1       20

8  3  2014/01/01  5       99
9  3  2014/01/02  5       99
10 3  2014/01/03  5       99
11 3  2014/01/04  5       99
12 3  2014/01/05  5       120
13 3  2014/01/06  5       120
14 3  2014/01/07  5       120
```

Need to get:

```
   A  B           C       D 
   id date        rating price
1  1              1.42    20
2  3              5       108
```

How to do that? Need some advanced formula or VB Script.

**Update:** I have data for long period - about 2 years. Need to calculate average values for **each** product for each **week**, and after for each **month**.

Source data example:

```
id date         rating
4   2013-09-01  445
4   2013-09-02  446
4   2013-09-03  447
4   2013-09-04  448
4   2013-09-05  449
4   2013-09-06  450
4   2013-09-07  451
4   2013-09-08  452
4   2013-09-09  453
4   2013-09-10  454
4   2013-09-11  455
4   2013-09-12  456
4   2013-09-13  457
4   2013-09-14  458
4   2013-09-15  459
4   2013-09-16  460
4   2013-09-17  461
4   2013-09-18  462
4   2013-09-19  463
4   2013-09-20  464
4   2013-09-21  465
4   2013-09-22  466
4   2013-09-23  467
4   2013-09-24  468
4   2013-09-25  469
4   2013-09-26  470
4   2013-09-27  471
4   2013-09-28  472
4   2013-09-29  473
4   2013-09-30  474
4   2013-10-01  475
4   2013-10-02  476
4   2013-10-03  477
4   2013-10-04  478
4   2013-10-05  479
4   2013-10-06  480
4   2013-10-07  481
4   2013-10-08  482
4   2013-10-09  483
4   2013-10-10  484
4   2013-10-11  485
4   2013-10-12  486
4   2013-10-13  487
4   2013-10-14  488
4   2013-10-15  489
4   2013-10-16  490
4   2013-10-17  491
4   2013-10-18  492
4   2013-10-19  493
4   2013-10-20  494
4   2013-10-21  495
4   2013-10-22  496
4   2013-10-23  497
4   2013-10-24  498
4   2013-10-25  499
4   2013-10-26  500
4   2013-10-27  501
4   2013-10-28  502
4   2013-10-29  503
4   2013-10-30  504
4   2013-10-31  505

7   2013-09-01  1445
7   2013-09-02  1446
7   2013-09-03  1447
7   2013-09-04  1448
7   2013-09-05  1449
7   2013-09-06  1450
7   2013-09-07  1451
7   2013-09-08  1452
7   2013-09-09  1453
7   2013-09-10  1454
7   2013-09-11  1455
7   2013-09-12  1456
7   2013-09-13  1457
7   2013-09-14  1458
7   2013-09-15  1459
7   2013-09-16  1460
7   2013-09-17  1461
7   2013-09-18  1462
7   2013-09-19  1463
7   2013-09-20  1464
7   2013-09-21  1465
7   2013-09-22  1466
7   2013-09-23  1467
7   2013-09-24  1468
7   2013-09-25  1469
7   2013-09-26  1470
7   2013-09-27  1471
7   2013-09-28  1472
7   2013-09-29  1473
7   2013-09-30  1474
7   2013-10-01  1475
7   2013-10-02  1476
7   2013-10-03  1477
7   2013-10-04  1478
7   2013-10-05  1479
7   2013-10-06  1480
7   2013-10-07  1481
7   2013-10-08  1482
7   2013-10-09  1483
7   2013-10-10  1484
7   2013-10-11  1485
7   2013-10-12  1486
7   2013-10-13  1487
7   2013-10-14  1488
7   2013-10-15  1489
7   2013-10-16  1490
7   2013-10-17  1491
7   2013-10-18  1492
7   2013-10-19  1493
7   2013-10-20  1494
7   2013-10-21  1495
7   2013-10-22  1496
7   2013-10-23  1497
7   2013-10-24  1498
7   2013-10-25  1499
7   2013-10-26  1500
7   2013-10-27  1501
7   2013-10-28  1502
7   2013-10-29  1503
7   2013-10-30  1504
7   2013-10-31  1505
```

Comment: Insert Pivot table,  play with it for a bit to become familiar with it,  show values as average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the job of a pivot table, and it takes about 30secs to do it

[image]

Update:
as per your update,  put the date into the Report Filter and modify to suit